# Meaning of Chrome Dev-tools Menubar Icon (anti-speaker)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I just noticed the icon indicated in the image below appearing in the menubar of my devtools window. What does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have muted this tab by right clicking on it in the main Chrome UX?

Looks to me like either that is causing it or the site itself is modifying the title if some sound is muted on the page. DevTools will inherit this title for the tab, so it is natural that it would show as well there.

Comment: What is interesting is that the parent tab has no audio and did not have that icon on it.

Comment: So, 1) try without an extensions. 2) Can you please provide a site where this reproduces? 3) Does this reproduce on all sites for you or just a sub-set (if sub-set then #2 is critical.)